# Why safari version over 13 not renders full images on iphones (new iphones 11+) ReactJs

Tags: ios, reactjs, image

i have problem with my React app. My images dont full render on new safari/iphones. On Androids, Windows and safari on mac everything is fine. Just look at this photo:
[iOS not loading full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9E0Q.png)

there is my component:

```jsx
<Dashboard.Avatar
    src={src}
    withDefaultImage={
        (src && src.includes('DefaultImage.png')) ||
        (currentSrc && currentSrc.includes('DefaultImage.png'))
    }
    onLoad={() => {
        setUserId()
        setTimeout(() => {
            setUserId(userId)
        }, 500)
    }}
    onError={e =>
        hooks.useFallbackImage(
            e,
            images.split(','),
            userId,
            usersNearby,
            setUsersNearby
        )
    }
/>
```

Sorry for my English. Im also React newbie. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it just added to div image parent:

```
display: flex;
```

and to image:

```
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
align-self: flex-start;
```